# Is there any way to have gcc issue warnings for implicit enum to int conversion in C?

Tags: c, enums, implicit-conversion

Is there any way to have gcc issue warnings for implicit enum to int (or vice versa) conversion in C (*not* C++).

I find that the implicit conversions can be a little bit sloppy, and I spend a long time tracking down a bug I caused which was related to this.

Comment: You may want to check out `Splint` http://www.splint.org/ otherwise I don't see a way. The manual section 4.1.2 looks helpful http://www.splint.org/manual/manual.html

Comment: Aren't `enum`s `int`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C there is no implicit conversion warning because the constants of an `enum` by definition of the language are of type `int` not of the `enum` type. If you'd have the compiler warn on these things you would have a warning in the second line but not the third:

```
enum things { thing };       //< declaration of a constant of type int
enum things thingy = thing;  //< implicit conversion from int to enum things
enum things thingi = thingy; //< no conversion
```